# Angular core directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there something called as core angular directives? I came across a question where it was asked to mention which one is NOT a core directive out of ng-app,ng-model,ng-view and ng-bind.
So I would like to understand the concept of how core directives are differentiated. 
I googled but could not find much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will get ng-app, ng-model and ng-bind in the core angular.js module.
ng-view is part of the angular-route module which needs to be loaded separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the list of Core Directives in Angular 1.x:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng
They are simply under: *ng*

And if you scroll down, you'll see more directives, part of other modules, like `ng-view`: under ngRoute:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute